# C# generics type resolving

Tags: c#, generics

I am writing a popup window service in for our mvvm application.

I have wrote this method in the popup controller

```
void ShowDialogWithResult<TView, TViewModel, TResult>(Action<TResult, WindowClosedEventArgs> callbackAction)
            where TView : FrameworkElement, IPopupContent<TViewModel>
            where TViewModel : IResultViewModel<TResult>;
```

As you can see to show a popup window with view model and result the view must implement `IPopupContent<TViewModel>` interface, and in its turn the view model must implement interface `IResultViewModel<TResult>`

So we have a chain of types started from TView->TViewModel->TResult

the call to such method looks like this:

```
 _childWindowController
                .ShowDialogWithResult<AddNationalityPopup,AddNationalityPopupModel, AddNationalityResult>(
                    (result, a) =>
                    {
                        if (a.DialogResult.HasValue && a.DialogResult.Value)
                        {
                            if (result.NationalityCountryId.HasValue)
                            {
                                Background.NationalityCountryId = result.NationalityCountryId.Value;
                                Background.NationalityDescription = result.NationalityDescription;
                            }
                        }
                    });
```

As you can see I am forced to pass all three type parameters for compiler to generate correct method.

And this code makes me sad. How can I reduce the amount of type parameters required by the call and still get type safety. I can't develop any valid solution.

Comment: How do you expect it to infer the type of `TResult`?

Comment: I had a feeling that covariance can handle it. 
Also if I could say compiler that there will be only single implementation of the IPopupContent and IResultViewModel, than the compiler can safely get type from view.

Comment: The compiler has no way of knowing that there will only ever be a single implementation of an interface. Even if it's true in the code you've written, and the interfaces are marked as `internal`, it has insufficient analytical power to rule out you constructing a new class on the fly using `Reflection.Emit` that implements that same interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way of reducing these generic type parameters in this call, but you can use inheritance in order to specialize it overloading this method.

For example, if there're a lot of calls to `.ShowDialogWithResult<AddNationalityPopup,AddNationalityPopupModel, ...>`, you can inherit your controller and add an overload like `.ShowDialogWithResult<TResult>`.

*Take 2:*

Another approach like this would be adding these method's generic type parameters to the controller class and using inversion of control, it can be instantiated with the appropiate type arguments freeing the caller of providing them in `.ShowDialogWithResult(...)`.

Comment: Unfortunately I am forced to have single instance of this controller, but anyway good point.

Comment: And why don't using inversion of control for choosing the right controller?